# can't delete an element from a hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, element

I created a hashmap to store object Person, the key is a String (Person's email address).  I am trying to delete an entry in the hashmap using the key but not sure why it won't delete it. What went wrong?  My code and the output are included.  any help is appreciated!

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class TestHashMap {

    private Map <String, Person> personDB = new HashMap<String, Person>();

    // added main to test the code
    public static void main(String[] args) {

TestHashMap org = new TestHashMap() ;

      // add data to personDB
org.add(new Person("A", "Smith","1234567890","ASmith@atest.com"));
org.add(new Person("B", "Smith","1234567890", "BSmith@atest.com"));
org.add(new Person("C", "Walsh","1234567890","CWalsh@atest.com"));
org.add(new Person("D", "Glatt","1234567890","DGlatt@atest.com"));
org.add(new Person("E", "Cheong", "1234567890","ACheong@atest.com"));
org.add(new Person("F", "Walsh","0123456789","FWalsh@sg.com"));

      // remove an element from personDB
org.display("testing ......before remove");  // display all elements in personDB
org.remove("ACheong@atest.com");
org.display("after..................");   
    }

    public void add(Person p) {
    String key = p.getEmail();
    personDB.put(key, p);
    }

    public void remove(String mail) {
Object obj = personDB.remove(personDB.get(mail));   
System.out.println(obj + " deleted!");
    }
}
```

My output:

```
testing ......before remove("ECheong@atest.com")
ID:[ASmith@atest.com]
ID:[CWalsh@atest.com]
ID:[FWalsh@sg.com]
ID:[ECheong@atest.com]
ID:[DGlatt@atest.com]
ID:[BSmith@atest.com]
null deleted!
after..................
ID:[ASmith@atest.com]
ID:[CWalsh@atest.com]
ID:[FWalsh@sg.com]
ID:[ECheong@atest.com]
ID:[DGlatt@atest.com]
ID:[BSmith@atest.com]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Object obj = personDB.remove(personDB.get(mail));
```

should be

```
Object obj = personDB.remove(mail);
```

The parameter to `remove` is the `key`, not the element.

Answer (score 0):

Person is the key, not "ACheong@atest.com"

This should work:

```
Person p = new Person("E", "Cheong", "1234567890","ACheong@atest.com");
org.remove(p);
```

Comment: Person is not the key.  `org` is his own class.  If you look at the `add` method, it uses `p.getEmail()` as the key.